# How to delete table data on RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm use of Ruby on Rails.

My models like this.

Weblog model

```
class Weblog < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
end
```

Comment model

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :comment
  belongs_to :weblog
end
```

My console log is here

```
$ attr = {}
$ attr["blog"] = {"body" => "test body", "comments_attributes" => {"0" => {"comment" => "comment1"}, "1" => {"comment" => "comment2"}}}
$ blog = Weblog.new(attr["blog"])
$ blog.save #=> comment data are saved with id 1 and 2 in comments table
$ attr["blog"] = {"body" => "update test body", "comments_attributes" => {"0" => {"comment" => "commentA", "id" => "1"}}} # I want to delete comment data whose id is 2 in comment table
$ blog2 = Weblog.first
$ blog2.update_attributes(attr["blog"]) #=> updates are correctly finished..
```

But the data whose id is 2 in comment table are not deleted.

How to delete comments table data through updating weblogs table.

Comment: So if someone edits his comments then everyone else's will disappear?  Having a hard time figuring your use case (and therefore what you're really trying to do).

Comment: blog.comments.find(2).destroy

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `allow_destroy => true` option to your `accepts_nested_attributes_for` call:

```
class Weblog < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the :allow_destroy option when declaring the model accepts nested attributes. After you do that, when you want to remove a nested model you need to pass the id of the model and the special attribute _destroy with value '1'

You can see the doc and an example at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html